# Cheese moved, no scroll wheel to move it back

Tags: bug, mobile-web, global-inbox

So, the new topbar has been rolled to mobile.

Which is nice, because I like the new topbar<sup>1</sup>.

However, the new inbox is a popup window<sup>2</sup> with `overflow:auto`. On some phones (mine is a Samsung Galaxy Mini), this gets cropped in strange places (I took the screenshot via Chrome, but I get the same thing on my phone)

[image]

(Yes, it does get cut off on the right, it's not a screenshot artifact)

I don't mind the cropping much, however I am unable to scroll down, since it's a phone and I don't have a scroll wheel.

Could this be fixed? Preferably replacing the popup with a functionality similar to the old one.

As far as I can tell, the inbox is the most used feature of the mobile site. One should be able to check their inbox and reply to comments without much issues on a mobile device.

<sup>1. Also, it looks like the old genuwine inbox is being phased out in its entirety(it's only left on chat now), which is good as there were issues with clearing the inbox once the topbar rolled out.</sup>

<sup>2. The old inbox would push the page content down, not come on top of it</sup>

Comment: Odd, on the galaxy s3 I can scroll by holding and dragging

Comment: @RichardTingle Tried that, doesn't work. Not all phones have multitouch. (Well, mine might, not sure, but the browser doesn't detect two finger scroll)

Comment: I think I might be misunderstanding. Is this: open inbox --> attempt to scroll to old items? For me that's a single finger scroll

Comment: @RichardTingle Not sure about old items, in my inbox the last item is clipped halfway (If it wasn't, then it would be believable that it is only showing new items -- which, fwiw, isn't a good thing either; what if I closed the inbox accidentally? I wouldn't be able to access it again). I've tried all kinds of scrolling, none work.

Comment: Are you on Android 2.3 or higher?

Comment: If it makes a difference;  although I can scroll to older items the last one (after I've scrolled for a bit) is awkwardly cut off too

Comment: @Stijn 2.2.3 (Froyo).

Comment: That version is not supported (see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need)), but [according to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_Mini) there's an official upgrade to 2.3.6 available.

Comment: @Stijn Hmm, I was unable to get the update to work. Also, the supported browsers page mentions that old versions are reasonably supported. The inbox is probably the most-used mobile feature, the other activities are harder by mobile but a quick check at the inbox is not. IMO this feature ought to be work for phone browsers, even older ones.

Comment: Not sure we have any devices that age to test browsers on since our app targets 4.0+, hopefully we can find one at the office.  If we can reasonably support it, we'll try to.

Comment: FYI - The old SuperCollider inbox is still active on Area 51 (a wonky work-around, but if you're just interested in your inbox, well - there's a place where it still behaves the same)

Comment: @TimPost ....area51 doesn't have a mobile site, so that doesn't work (the full site will load, but will take longer and is tiny). Thanks though

Comment: @NickCraver Thanks! Are you sure that the clipping of the sides doesn't happen on newer browsers as well? Because I'm seeing it on Chrome -- admittedly not a mobile device, but it does know all the newfangled CSS attributes.

Comment: (Also, since scrolling on many mobile devices -- even newer ones -- is a pain, maybe it would be better to not show it as a popup?)

Comment: We are looking at moving some more cheese on mobile web and this would definitely be impacted.